# Add message to messageTop when exporting DataTables to Excel

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am exporting a table into Excel using the DataTables plugin. I would like to add some data before exporting. Therefore I am trying to add `messagetop` in Excel action function but it's not working.

```js
buttons: [{
  extend: 'excelHtml5',
  title: 'Arrival Order',
  messageTop: true,
  action: function(e, dt, button, config) {
    var info = dt.buttons.exportInfo();
    info.messageTop = "helloooo!!!!!!!!";
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.excelHtml5.action.call(this, e, dt, button, config);
  }
}]
```

I should be able to see `hellooo!!!` in the report.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do it like this?

```
buttons: [{
  extend: 'excelHtml5',
  title: 'Arrival Order',
  messageTop: "helloooo!!!!!!!!",
}]
```

Comment: I am able to display  messageTop but now I want to make it multiple lines because I have lengthy data.

Comment: Try adding newline characters to the String. `messageTop: "helloooo\n\rsecond line"` **Notice** that newlines don't show in excel's basic display, only after you double click / edit a cell.

Answer (score 0):

```
buttons: [{
  extend: 'excelHtml5',
  title: 'Arrival Order',
  message: "helloooo!!!!!!!!"
}]
```

instend of messageTop use Message